# Tomcat server's JVM free memory not returned to OS

Tags: tomcat, memory, jvm, debian

My tomcat server is behaving strange, it has allocated 6GB of memory from system, but more than 4GB is marked as "free".

This is a screen from tomcat server status:
[image]

I understand what "Free memory" in JVM means, but I do not understand why it is not returning lets say in this situation at least 3GB back to system.

Env:

- Java 8
- Tomcat 8
- Debian 8.3
- Total memory on machine: 64 GB

Comment: What JVM options are used? The ability to return heap memory back to system depends on the selected GC flags.

Comment: I am not using any additional flags, all tomcat configs are default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you haven't overridden any JVM options, Tomcat uses the default garbage collector which is ParallelGC in JDK 8.

ParallelGC does not uncommit heap memory. Try `-XX:+UseG1GC` option. G1 garbage collector
is capable of releasing memory back to the OS.

See [this article](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2017/11/minimize-java-memory-usage-right-garbage-collector.html) for more information.

Comment: I have changed to G1 Garbage Colletor, but I am facing the same issue, the memory pool looks different, but still I have 3+ GB of memory marked as "free" that is never unallocated back to OS.

Edit: after 5 minutes it deallocated those 3GB back to OS. Thanks if works.

Comment: @Welite Yes, the memory is not uncommitted immediately. This happens only after Full GC.

Comment: Question and answer are few years old, but I face the very same issue right now on 2 systems (locally and customer) and on both systems the tomcat has the G1GC setting, but free space is not given back, ever. Are there more variables/things to consider nowadays?